# webdriver.io & cucumber-js examine memory leaks

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io, cucumberjs

We have many scenarios that test our solution in using [webdriver.io](http://webdriver.io/) + [cucumber.js](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js) and we wanted to test our client side memory consumption & performance plus automate this as a scenario inside our test suite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After different try and errors we had found that the simple's way to monitor it is to use google chrome dev-tools manually 
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/

and record every release the metrics observed.